# Vertical TikZ arrow anchored to the center of the target

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[left] at (0,0) (Source) {Source};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (0.15,-0.02) -- (2.5,0.48);
    \node[right] at (2.5,0.5) (Target1) {abcdefgh};
    \node at (Target1) (Target1arrow) {};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (2.35,0.52) -- (0,0.02);
    \node[right] at (2.5,-0.5) (Target2) {abcdefg};
    \node at (Target2) (Target2arrow) {};
    \draw [very thick, ->] (0.15,-0.02) -- (2.5,-0.5);
    \draw [very thick, ->, shorten <= .5ex, shorten >= .5ex] (Target1arrow) -- (Target2arrow);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that the vertical arrow starts from the midpoint of `Target1` and points to the midpoint of `Target2`, but in this case where the lengths of these two targets are almost identical, it would look better if the arrow was straight. In other words, I'd like the start of the arrow to be anchored to the center point of `Target2`. I tried adding `anchor = Target2.base` to the drawing function of this arrow, but it had no effect.

Comment: I think that `|-` inside the node name would do it, but right know I don't remember the exact syntax. By the way, why not put the node `abcdefg` below `abcdefgh`?

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning, you could use relative positioning. Load the `positioning` library and write something like: `\node (target1) {abcdefgh}; \node (target2) [below=of target1] {abcdefg}; \draw [->] (target1) -- (target2);`. This way `TikZ` automatically draws edges coming from and going to the centers of the nodes.

Comment: @PierPaolo But then what sets the vertical distance between ``Target1`` and ``Target2``?

Comment: You could write: `\node (target2) [below=1cm of target1] {abcdefg};`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there's the option of putting the node below the other one (Pier Paolo explained).

And there's also the syntax `(node1 |- node2)` which draws the line vertically. In this case, the end of the arrow is written as `(Target1arrow |- Target2arrow.north)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[left] at (0,0) (Source) {Source};
  \draw [very thick, ->] (0.15,-0.02) -- (2.5,0.48);
  \node[right] at (2.5,0.5) (Target1) {abcdefgh};
  \node at (Target1) (Target1arrow) {};
  \draw [very thick, ->] (2.35,0.52) -- (0,0.02);
  \node[right] at (2.5,-0.5) (Target2) {abcdefg};
  \node at (Target2) (Target2arrow) {};
  \draw [very thick, ->] (0.15,-0.02) -- (2.5,-0.5);
  \draw [very thick, ->, shorten <= .5ex, shorten >= .5ex] (Target1arrow) -- (Target1arrow |- Target2arrow.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but when I try to compile this with pdfLaTeX, it freezes when loading ``~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg``.

Comment: @Sverre because it's missing `\end{document}`?

Comment: @AdamLiter Added :)

Comment: Is there a way to change the starting point of the arrow? In this case, it's the end point of the arrow which has been changed.

Comment: @Sverre The same way. That's the syntax. `(node1 |- node2)` is a syntax to refer to a point, the same as `(nodename1.north)` or `(nodename1.227)`. You can use it as a starting point or wherever you want.

Comment: @Sverre yep! Just do `\draw [very thick, ->, shorten <= .5ex, shorten >= .5ex] (Target1arrow -| Target2arrow.south) -- (Target2arrow);` instead.

Comment: @Sverre I understand now, you *explicitly* asked for an arrow that went vertical to the center of `Target2arrow` (I missed that part from the question). AdamLiter's comment is the way to go.